# Why does $z=(x+yi)^n$ have such strange behavior?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, radicals, surfaces, symmetry

Inspired from:

> ["The Egg:" Bizarre behavior of the roots of a family of polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206890/the-egg-bizarre-behavior-of-the-roots-of-a-family-of-polynomials).

And much more information is at:

> [**Wolfram Functions 3D plots over the complex planes for $z^a$**](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Power/visualizations/2/)

I came to notice that a surface plot of $$z=(x+yi)^n$$ had a saddle or a singularity made n lines of symmetry from the origin. Here are a few plots of the real part for simplicity:

**Positive n:** Notice the “saddle” shape and n lines of symmetry:

$n=3$:

[image]

$n=30$:

[image]

$n=2\pi$:

[image]

**Negative n** Notice the essential singularity at x=y=0 and n lines of symmetry:

$n=-3$:

[image]

$n=-10$:

[image]

$n=-3.7$:

[image]

**$|n|<1$:**: The closer to 0 the fraction is, the more circular the plot looks. The closer to 1 that n is, then the more it looks like a plane. A similar concept applies for $1<n<2$ and $-2<n<1$:

$n=\frac12$:

[image]

$n=-\frac12$:

[image]

**Complex n:** There seems to be no clear pattern other than a complex amount of “lines of symmetry”. We can also use [De Moivre’s](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) formula to split z into real and imaginary parts. Notice the oscillation:

$n=4i$:

[image]

$n=-2-3i$:

[image]

$n=-1-4i$:

[image]

$n=\frac1e-\frac1{\sqrt2}i:$

[image]

$n=6+i$:[image]

I already have some observations, but I would like to know what a graph of $$z=(x+yi)^n$$ would look like for a given n. For example, why does each bigger value of $|n|\in\Bbb R$ add more lines of symmetry and why does $n\in\Bbb C$ have such peculiar oscillatory behavior? I am guessing it has to do with the Riemann Surfaces of $z^n$. Also note that the argument of z will give insights as well. Please correct me and give me feedback!

The mystery of the symmetry has been solved by @Thomas Andrews, but behavior  for complex and imaginary is still an open problem. If you have a better proof for real n than @Thomas Andrews, then please feel free to write it.

Comment: If $\zeta_n=\cos(2\pi/n)+i\sin(2\pi/n)$ then $\zeta_n^n=1.$ sMultiplication by $\zeta_n$ rotates a complex number by $\frac{2\pi}{n}.$ And if $f(z)=z_n,$ then $f(\zeta_n z)=f(z),$ so you expect an $n$-fold rotational symmetry in the graph of $f(x+yi).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is there any interpretation of the n-fold symmetry of $\mathrm{\frac{full\ turn}{power}=\frac{2\pi}{n}}$ for $n\in\Bbb C$? and not just real-n fold symmetry? It seems like hyperbolic trigonometric functions are involved for pure imaginary n.

Comment: It isn’t even possible to make $z^n$ continuous on all of $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ if $n$ is not an integer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes for example for $n\in \Bbb C, n=a+bi;a,b\in\Bbb R$ assuming a _principal branch_:
$\mathrm{(x+yi)^{a+bi}=(x+yi)^a ((x+yi)^i)^b=(x+yi)^ae^{bi\,ln(x+yi)}=(x+yi)^a [cos(b\,ln(x+yi))+i\,sin(b\,ln(x+yi))]=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\,tan^{-1}\frac yx}+ [cos(b\,ln(x+yi))+i\,sin(b\,ln(x+yi))]}$ Please also see [this similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476968/complex-power-of-a-complex-number). Now all that is left is to find ln(x+yi)  seen [Re and Im parts of ln(z).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260028/find-the-real-and-imaginary-parts-of-lnz). Is this good?